# Arraylist of Custom Object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

This is a fairly simple question, but I am a beginner and I've been stuck on this part for hours now. I am not looking for an easy way out, but instead I just want to understand what is happening to my code and why it isn't working. My problem was:

Create a node class with a random number and the current time.
Create a storage class and store those nodes in a list/array.
Use the main class to create 50 nodes and display.

When I run it 50 times and get my list, I made the list print out the time so that I could check to see if my code was running, and they all have the same time. It means that different nodes aren't being stored into my list, and are instead being wiped out each time the loop runs. Why is that?

My code is attached:

Main:

```
public class NodeSort {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int c = 0;
    while (c < 50)
    {
        Storage.add();
        c++; 
    }


}

}
```

Node:

```
public class Node
{
public static int num;
public static long time;

public Node()
{
    num = Random.getNum();
    time = System.nanoTime();
}

public static long getTime()
{
    return time;
}

public static int getNum()
{
    return num;
}
}
```

Storage:

```
public class Storage 
{
public static ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();

public static void add()
{

    list.add(new Node());

}
```

When I do get time for x = 1-50, it prints out the same time 50 times instead of 50 different ones.

Comment: Show the printing code.

Comment: You might be generating the same random number since it's running pretty fast.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your output? I'm not sure I'm clear on it. Where exactly are you printing your output to a list? Also, why are you using `nanoTime()`?

Comment: Please show your output.

Comment: AD a random number generator has a seed that would increment, speed is irrelevant here unless it is a custom (broken) implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They all have the same `time` value because they're all getting created at almost the same time.  `System.nanoTime()` doesn't guarantee that you'll actually get nanosecond precision, it's up to the operating system's ability to discern time.  Most OSes can only provide millisecond resolution.  So if all of the calls happen within the same millisecond, you'll get the same values.

As far as the random number is concerned, I don't know--what is the `Random` class?  It's not `java.util.Random`.

Edit: Oh wait, I see it.  You declared `num` and `time` as `static` in your `Node` class.  That means there's only one copy of each in existence.  Just remove `static` from those declarations, and from the methods that return the values.

Comment: I know the first point isn't right, because if I print them out while the loop is still running, I get 50 different numbers. It is only when I access them from the list that they're all the same. The 2nd point might be the reason. As for the random, it's a class I made, but I just didn't include the code. I'll try to see if the static was the probem. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, your 2nd tip fixed it. Thanks a lot for the answer! I'm still confused on what static is and how it differs/why it cannot be called from a nonstatic class. Any readings you can point me to for further information?

Comment: @MehtabC -- `static` marks the field or method as belonging to the class as a whole, rather than to each individual instance.  Think of a class declaration like a cookie cutter, and each time you call `new MyClass()` that uses the cookie cutter to stamp out a new cookie.  `static` means the field/method belongs to the cookie cutter, not each individual cookie.  They're commonly used for constants, and for utility/helper functions that don't depend on any particular instance.